# Getting value with javascript and use it in controller

Tags: scala, playframework

First of all i am using play framework with scala,
What i have to do is , using the data which i am getting with that function;

```
onClick: function(node) {

        if(!node) return;
       alert(node.id);
       var id = node.id;

      }
```

So what the question is how i can call the methods from controller with this id ? Since js is client-side but scala works with server-side , i need something creative.
This is the function i need to call from my controller.

```
 def supertrack(id:Long) = Action {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found out that i need use ScalaJavaScriptRouting in order to send a ajax request to the server.

For the documentation

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJavascriptRouting